# In Functional Programming, should domain-relevant simple functions (e.g., sorts) be reified?

Tags: design, coding-style, functional-programming

In a functional application, should you wrap common higher-level functions in domain-meaningful names or should you leave them "bare"?

For instance, if you have a list of Addresses, and "sorted by zipcode" is a common domain-meaningful ordering (targeted mailers, etc.), is it preferable to write:

```
val sortedCustomers = customers.sort((a,b) => (a.zipCode compareTo b.zipCode) < 0)
```

Or is it better to create a function `sortedByZip(cs : Iterable[Customer]) : Seq[Customer]`?

Creating the function has the advantage of being (minutely) more abstract, but has the disadvantage of being opaque, creating a name to remember, etc.

I'm asking in the context of a significant professional codebase, one that you intend to live for years, be as maintainable as possible, be "true" to the expectations of functional programmers, etc.

Comment: in haskell the right side would be `sortBy (compare 'on' zipCode) customers` :D (except ` instead of ')

Comment: You can get backticks inside code spans: ``compare `on` zipCode``. The trick is to start and end the span with *two* backticks, so single backticks are allowed inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends (but then, you knew that). If this call site is the only place customers are sorted, then I'd leave it as is for the moment. If the sorting code were more complicated (CC > 1), I'd definitely extract a function for the sorting criterion. If I had ten call sites like the one above, I would definitely have a sortedCustomers() function. Somewhere between 1 and 10 (really between 2-4, assuming I noticed the duplication), I'd extract the function.

Answer (score 0):

I usually keep make a distinction between natural/canonical domain order and arbitrary order. If zipcode is a canonical order in this domain I would write the function as: customers.inNaturalOrder().

If you add a sortBy function you can have something like this: customers.sortBy(_.zipCode), which reads much better a

Minor nitpick, byZipCode reads like grouping to me, I would expect it to return a multimap of zipcode to customers.

Comment: Question edited to address your "`byZipCode` implies grouping" point